# How to pop-up the "Cellular data is Turned Off" warning message?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Apple's built-in applications show a pop-up message whenever the user doesn't have cellular or wifi connectivity. It looks something like:

"Cellular data is Turned Off

Turn on cellular data or use Wi-Fi to access data

[Settings] [OK]"

Clicking on the Settings button opens the settings panel.

Is this a system pop-up? How can I use it in my own application?

I'm already using UIRequiresPersistentWiFi but it uses a different type of message which appears when airplane mode is on.

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could post the code in which you're querying the reachability APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Application uses Wi-Fi in info.plist. Then this warning is displayed when cellular data is turned off and you're not connected to wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Reachability example in Apple's Sample code.  It will give you all the code you need to determine if you're connected or not to the internet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for. I'm already using reachability to determine connectivity. But the functionality I described in my post appears to be an OS-level message box and I'm looking for a way to use it so that my application experience is consistent with Apple's.

Comment: You might want to check out TSAlertView, which allows you to customize your own alerts to look just like Apple's, or like anything else frankly.  https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView